# Different ways to select class elements

Tags: jquery

I am looking for all the possibilities to select elements of a class in jQuery.

```
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap">
```

I know I can select the first and the last element by using:

```
   $('div.wrap:first').
   $('div.wrap:last').
```

`[0], [1]` doesn't seem to work in jQuery or I am doing it wrong. Is there any other possibily to select the elements (not the first and last one)?

Comment: use ID on your elements

Comment: I want to know "all" the possibilities to select **one** class element, not one possibility to select all class elements.. if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

`$("div.wrap:first-child")` and `$("div.wrap:last-child")` for first and last.

`$("div.wrap:nth-child(4)")` for the 4th element

`$("div.wrap:even")` for even elements (2nd, 4th, 6th, etc)

`$("div.wrap:nth-child(4n+1)")` for (4n+1)-th elements (1st, 5th, 9th, etc)

`$("div.wrap:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)")` for not-first, not-last element.

And so on :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Do you have any idea why some of those commands work and some don't? `$('div.wrap:nth-child(1)').` doesn't work while `$('div.wrap:first').` and `$('div.wrap.even').` work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use not

```
  $("div.wrap:not(:first):not(:last)").each(function(){....})
```

Working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/timus2001/qnvou2k7/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".wrap")[1]
```

this will work.

```
$(".wrap")
```

returns an array.

You can also try ..

```
$("[class='wrap']")
$("div[class='wrap']")
 $("[class^='wr']")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HTML DOM getElementsByClassName() Method

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");

$(".wrap")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try java script code

```
document.getElementsByClassName('wrap');
```